# Running Talend jobs with Python

Tags: python, automation, talend

I'm trying to automate some stuff I would otherwise have to do manually, so I can run one python script instead of taking a whole bunch of steps. I want to find a way to run a Talend job from the python script.

How do I accomplish this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops! sorry. 
From the Studio, build the job to get an autonomous job you can launch from command line.
Extract the files from the generated archive.
Search for folder "script/yourJobname".
Check the syntax from one of the .bat or .sh depending of which one you prefer.
Launch the jar file using subprocess.call (or other way to execute a jar file from Python).

Hope this helps.
TRF

Comment: alright, I found the .sh and .bat files, they were under `JobName_0.1.zip/JobName` Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

As soon as you can run a Python script from command line, you should be able to run it from Talend using tSystem component.

Comment: I'm not trying to run the python script from Talend, I'm trying to execute a Talend job with Python.