# How to run or execute Talend jobs through python script?

Tags: python, talend

I need to run a talend job outside of the talend studio. Is there any way to execute a talend job through python script ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Talend jobs with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209681/running-talend-jobs-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common task and the following link gives detailed step by step procedure to create a .bat/.sh /jar.

https://community.talend.com/t5/Migration-Configuration-and/Exporting-a-Job-script-and-executing-it-outside-of-Talend-Studio/ta-p/21686

Once you create the job, then you can trigger it from python using subprocess.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['(path)talendJob.jar'])
```

Answer (score 0):

normally you can use any processmanagement tool to do that. For example
supervisor http://supervisord.org/. That's a processmanagement based
on python.